# Фильтр сортировки съедает карусель

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет! Есть сайт на wordpress [тема](http://velikorodnov.com/wordpress/flatastic/classic/) которого построена с помощью visual composer. На сайте присутствует фильтр товаров (код ниже)

```html
<ul class="product-filter">
  <li class="active animate-left-to-right animate_finished">
    <button data-filter="*" value="All">Все</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button data-filter="discount">Hoodies&Sweatshirts</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button data-filter="vegetarian">Skirts</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button data-filter="new">Новинки</button>
  </li>
  <li class="animate-left-to-right animate_finished">
    <button data-filter="sale">Акция</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

А под фильтром в отдельном блоке расположена карусель. 
Если переходить по заголовкам фильтра, то owl карусель исчезает (если вместо карусели выбрать сеточную структуру элементов, то все ок, но мне нужна именно карусель!). Почему так происходит - догадываюсь, т.к. в карусели присутствует свой фильтр, по сути такой же как и в сетке, но почему на сетку не оказывает никакого влияния, а на карусель да? где искать конфликты?

Для наглядной демонстрации добавил тему на - [тестовый сайт](http://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/22/). Вверху находится фильтр, в самом низу карусель с товарами. Если переходим по вкладкам фильтра - нижняя карусель пропадает и появляется только после обновления страницы

Comment: Такая запись `<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>`
может выручить?